# Nestedlist not showing store data when inside panel

Tags: panel, sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

I'm having a problem loading my nestedlist data when this list is shown inside of a panel.
Here is my code:

```
    var titleBar = Ext.create("Ext.TitleBar", {
            id: 'mainNavigationBar',
            xtype : 'titlebar',
            layout: 'hbox',
            docked: 'top',
            title : 'cSenchaTitleBar',
            items:[
                {
                    xtype:"button",
                    text:"Menu",
                    align:"left",
                    listeners:{
                        tap: function(){
                             nestedListxx.showBy(this);
                        }
                    }
                },
            ]
        });


    var nestedList = 
        Ext.create('Ext.NestedList', {
            displayField: 'text',
            title:"cSenchaMenu",
            store: "oNavStore",
            id: 'mainNestedList',
            xtype : 'nestedlist',
            width:250,
            useTitleAsBackText: false,


         });
     var nestedListxx = Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
         width:260,
        items:nestedList
    });
```

The problem is the following:
Say that if I change
`nestedListxx.showBy(this);` to `nestedList.showBy(this);`
It works like a charm, only there are no sleek black borders around the nested list.
But if I change it back it does show the nestedlist with the nice borders but without any data.

I know for sure that I forgot to set some key configuration, only the question is: which ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set a layout to your `Ext.Panel`.

Try :

```
var nestedListxx = Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
    width:260,
    layout:'fit',
    items:nestedList
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew it was a config error on my end. One more question though, what config should I set to make the list not render to the end of the page but as long as itself?